# floating two divs next to each other at all times?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put two divs next to eachother at all times and so far nothing seems to work..

the divs width has to be 50% of the screen!

I need all the divs to have the same class as well so I can't do:

```
div1
div2
div1
div2

etc...
```

here is what I have done so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/dp8yktcg/

and this is the simple CSS:

```
.baners{
    width: 50%;
    height: 65vw; 
    border:solid 1px #D8D8D8;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#FFF;


}
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: I don't think you can have 4 `divs` with `width: 50%;` to be inline

Comment: @NenadVracar, I don't want 4 divs next to each-other. I need 2 div's in each row if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set `box-sizing` property to `border-box`, then use float, or remove whitespace between divs:

```
.baners{
    width: 50%;
    height: 65vw; 
    border:solid 1px #D8D8D8;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#FFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left; 
}

<div  class="someClass" >
    <div class="baners" >
    </div><div  class="baners" >
    </div><div class="baners" >
    </div><div  class="baners">
    </div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

They will never stay in the same line because of the 1 pixel border.

There are 2 ways you can make them stay in the same line.

**The first** (better) is to use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Doing so the element will be **50% width always**, despite borders and padding.

**The second** is to use the **calc** function for the width.

`width: calc(50% - 2px);`

By using this function you will remove 2px of the borders from the total width.

Remember to update this if you add any padding or increase the border width! (Anyway i suggest you the first option)

**EDIT**

I forgot that there's an issue with `display: inline-block;` basically a whitespace will be added between the two elements, covering more than 100%. To prevent this you can just add `float: left` or add a negative margin to the right, like `margin-right: -4px;`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `display:inline-block`, float them left and set the box-sizing to border-box.

```css
.baners {
    width: 50%;
    height: 65vw;
    border:solid 1px #D8D8D8;
    float:left;
    background:#eee;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="someClass">
    <div class="baners"></div>
    <div class="baners"></div>
    <div class="baners"></div>
    <div class="baners"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'box-shadow' to accomplish this. 
The problem is that 50% +1px is more than half of the screen and since your container isn't 100%+4px, the second box pushes to the next line, so what we want to do is essentially draw the border inside the 50%.

```
.baners{
box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 1px black inset;
width: 50%;
height: 65vw; 
display:inline-block;
background:red;
float:left;
```

}

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dp8yktcg/7/